# Delete specific docs in elasticsearch using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch. I am trying to delete a group of data from *http://localhost:9200/es_index/es_type* using python.

suppose **`x=['a','b','c','d','e','f']`** is a list of **`_ids`** that I want to delete

**Code:**

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 
es = Elasticsearch()
request_body = {
        "query": {
            "ids": {
                "values": ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
            }
        }
    }
es.delete_by_query(index=es_index, body=request_body)
```

But when I check *http://localhost:9200/es_index/es_type* the data is still there.

Comment: Which version of ES are you running?

Comment: the version is 6.1.0

Comment: And which version of `elasticsearch-py`?

Answer (score 2):

Please specify your ES and `elasticsearch-py` version in comments. Also you forgot to mention the value of `es_index` in your code, so make sure to pass the right one.

If the index is properly set, issue with `delete_by_query` usually comes from the query itself. Try to run a simple `search` with the same body and check that you get the desired results. It is always wise to do so to prevent mistakes.

In your case you know the id, so it is more appropriate to use `es.delete` and pass the id value :

```
for id in ids:
    es.delete(es_index=index, doc_type=_type, id=id)
```

With many documents you should consider using `bulk` helper to improve performance. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078887/how-to-execute-this-curl-in-python-2-7-to-delete-documents-from-elasticsearch).

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be delete_by_query, where you can directly pass a list of ids.

```
es = Elasticsearch()

def delete_by_id(index, ids):
    query = {"query": {"terms": {"Id":ids}}}
    es.delete_by_query(index=index, body=query)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can follow the [Delete by Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query) section on documentation and make a simple POST request to your index:

let's say that your index is named '*index_test*'. So, you can send a POST request to your index_url + '*_delete_by_query*', so the content (document) of your index will be deleted but the index itself will be preserved:

```
curl -X POST http://elasticAddress:9200/index_test/_delete_by_query
```

With this, you will not lose your visualization content as the index is preserved, but the document (content) is updated.