# How to execute this CURL in python 2.7 to delete documents from Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, elasticsearch

Hello I am new to python and elasticsearch. On my local I have setup Elasticsearch and have added data to it. http://127.0.0.1:9200/index_data/type_data.

I want to delete some _ids from the type_data.
suppose the list of _ids are x= ['a','b','c'.'d'] that i want to delete.

**curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/index_data/type_data/a?pretty'**

*using this command I was able to delete a particular _id from elasticsearch but how do execute this curl request using python?*

*Is it possible to delete the entire type_data using python?*

*why is this code not working*?

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 
es = Elasticsearch()
request_body = {
    "query": {
        "ids": {
            "values": ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
        }
    }
}
es.delete_by_query(index=es_index, body=request_body)
```

i am using
Elasticsearch version 6.1.0.
elasticsearch-py version 5.4.0

Please Help me!

Answer (score 1):

If there are a lot of ids, try parallel_bulk deletion in python:
documentaion here: http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.parallel_bulk

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers

es = Elasticsearch()
index_name = es_index
doc_type = your_doc_type
ids = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']


def generate_actions(ids):
    for i in ids:
        yield {
            '_op_type': 'delete',
            '_index': index_name,
            '_type': doc_type,
            '_id': i
        }


for success, info in helpers.parallel_bulk(client=es, actions=generate_actions(ids), thread_count=4):
    if not success: 
        print('Doc failed', info)
```

Comment: however for retrieve all documents with a specific data_type the best practice is to use the scan query - scroll api. In Python: helpers.scan(es,
    query={"query": {
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
},
    index="es_index",
    doc_type="your_data_type"
)